# Android 4.4.2 Request https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all Unable success

Tags: android, okhttp

Android system 4.4.2

Request address https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

Use implementation `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.0` to request success, use implementation `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp: 3.10.0`

Unable to request success prompt `ssl handshake failure`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What does your code look like? Please include a [mcve] which reproduces the issue. This helps us figure out if it is an issue with your implementation, or something else.